# get jsvc to listen to ipv4

Tags: linux, ipv6, ipv4, jsvc

I am setting up email archiving and it requires jsvc. I have set this up but running the following command shows it is not listening to ipv4. How can i change this?

```
netstat -pan --tcp | grep jsvc
tcp        0      0 :::8888                     :::*                        LISTEN      3180/jsvc.exec      
tcp        0      0 :::2526                     :::*                        LISTEN      3180/jsvc.exec      
tcp        0      0 :::2527                     :::*                        LISTEN      3180/jsvc.exec      
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.16.0.3:43930     ::ffff:172.16.0.3:27017     ESTABLISHED 3180/jsvc.exec      
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.16.0.3:43929     ::ffff:172.16.0.3:27017     ESTABLISHED 3180/jsvc.exec
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't listen on IPv4? Did you try `telnet -4 host port`?

Comment: telnet works so what does this mean. it is working?